# Scala: Unspecified value parameter evidence$3

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've looked around and found several other examples of this, but I don't really understand from those answers what's actually going on.

I'd like to understand why the following code fails to compile:

```
val df = readFiles(sqlContext).
    withColumn("timestamp", udf(UDFs.parseDate _)($"timestamp"))
```

Giving the error:

```
Error:(29, 58) not enough arguments for method udf: (implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[java.sql.Date], implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String])org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction.
Unspecified value parameter evidence$3.
            withColumn("timestamp", udf(UDFs.parseDate _)($"timestamp")).
                                                         ^
```

Whereas this code *does* compile:

```
val parseDate = udf(UDFs.parseDate _)
val df = readFiles(sqlContext).
    withColumn("timestamp", parseDate($"timestamp"))
```

Obviously I've found a "workaround" but I'd really like to understand:

1. What this error really means. The info I have found on `TypeTag`s and `ClassTag`s has been really difficult to understand. I don't come from a Java background, which perhaps doesn't help, but I think I should be able to grasp it…
2. If I can achieve what I want without a separate function definition

Comment: I'm not familiar with spark yet, but it seems that you are trying to create a `UserDefinedfunction` (using the `udf` method) and call its apply method in one go. The problem is that  `udf` has a second list of parameters (the second one being the implicit parameters list) so the compiler thinks that you want to pass `($"timestamp")` as the second parameter list. In short this is a purely syntactic ambiguity. Try doing `udf(UDFs.parseDate _).apply($"timestamp")` instead. Or capture the udf first, as in `val myUdf = udf(UDFs.parseDate _); ... withColumn("timestamp",myUdf($"timestamp"))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message is a bit mis-leading indeed; the reason for it is that the function `udf` takes an implicit parameter list but you are passing an actual parameter. Since I don't know much about spark and since the `udf` signature is a bit convoluted I'll try to explain what is going on with a simplified example.

In practice `udf` is a function that given some explicit parameters and an implicit parameter list gives you another function; let's define the following function that given a `pivot` of type `T` for which we have an implicit `Ordering` will give as a function that allows us to split a sequence in two, one containing elements smaller than `pivot` and the other containing elements that are bigger:

```
def buildFn[T](pivot: T)(implicit ev: Ordering[T]): Seq[T] => (Seq[T], Seq[T]) = ???
```

Let's leave out the implementation as it's not important. Now, if I do the following:

```
val elements: Seq[Int] = ???
val (small, big) = buildFn(10)(elements)
```

I will make the same kind of mistake that you are showing in your code, i.e. the compiler will think that I am explicitly passing `elements` as the implicit parameter list and this won't compile. The error message of my example will be somewhat different from the one you have because in my case the number of parameters I am mistakenly passing for the implicit parameter list matches the expected one and then the error will be about types not lining up.

Instead, if I write it as:

```
val elements: Seq[Int] = ???
val fn = buildFn(10)
val (small, big) = fn(elements)
```

In this case the compiler will correctly pass the implicit parameters to the function. I don't know of any way to circumvent this problem, unless you want to pass the actual implicit parameters explicitly but I find it quite ugly and not always practical; for reference this is what I mean:

```
val elements: Seq[Int] = ???
val (small, big) = buildFn(10)(implicitly[Ordering[Int]])(elements)
```

Comment: In your example, you can also do `(buildFn(10) _)(elements)` or `buildFn(10).apply(elements)`. Same can be done for `udf` application.

Comment: Good point @PatrykĆwiek - those will be good ways to make it on one line without incurring in this problem!

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. Indeed calling `.apply()` explicitly works.